# Связи Rails has_many belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Создал связи:

```
class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end


class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :material
end
```

У `item` появился метод `item.material.name`

Как сделать так, чтобы у `material` появился метод `material.items.name`

То есть, нужно, чтобы отображались все `items` этого `material`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас связь "Один ко многим". У одного `Material` много `Item`.
Для того, чтобы отобразить имена всех `Item`, связанных с данным `Material` их нужно перебрать.

Что-то вроде:

```
material.items.each do |item|
  puts item.name # Вот здесь будет доступно `name`
end
```

Если вы используете ERB шаблоны, то будет примерно так:

```
<ul>
    <% material.items.each do |item| %>
        <li><%= item.name %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `material' for #<#<Class:0x007f23dd2fff28>:0x007f23dd2fe560> может в контроллере что то дописать нужно?

Comment: Разобрался надо было добавить
<ul>
    <% @material.items.each do |item| %>
        <li><%= item.name %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>